# How to test a React ref with a callback?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, callback, jestjs, enzyme

Enzyme docs contains how to test a node having `ref` with `wrapper.ref('nameOfRef')`, but this only works for refs having just a string value like, if I have a node in React:

```
<span ref="secondRef" amount={4}>Second</span>
```

Then its test would be written like:

```
expect(wrapper.ref('secondRef').prop('amount')).to.equal(4);
```

But if I have a ref with a callback, then how to test it? Enzyme docs [1] does not says anything about this. For example, if I have a node with a ref like this:

```
<SomeCustomReactElement ref={_form => form = _form} />
```

Thanks for guidance.

`[1]: http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/ref.html`

Comment: What's your goal in testing the ref? If you just want to test for that component, why don't you do a `find` on `SomeCustomReactElement` instead? Also, in your ref you need to do `ref={_form => this.form = _form}`...

Comment: Actually, `form` is a local variable and after ref, there's another function that uses that `form`. So if ref is not tested, I cannot test the other function that's using `form`. Regarding `find` on custom element, how'd I do that? Likewise, we are using a totally different approach internally to avoid the use of `this`.

Comment: Re: `form`, ah, I see. Re: `ref`, from the [Enzyme docs](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/find.html), looks like you could do something like `expect(wrapper.find(SomeCustomReactComponent).prop('amount')).to.equal(4)` as long as you have imported `SomeCustomReactComponent` in the `spec` file.

Comment: Which `spec` file you're talking about?

Comment: By `spec` file, I mean your test file...our team refers to them as `spec` files.

Comment: I've tried, but it does not worked out. Somehow, I think the only concern is to somehow refer to the `ref`. Like, if `ref="IamRef"` then we can refer to that `ref` via `wrapper.ref('IamRef')` but in the mentioned case where `ref` contains a call-back, how to refer to the `ref` in test?

Answer (score 1):

You can call the `ref` callback manually using `wrapper.getElement()['ref'](mockRef)`.

E.g.

`index.tsx`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export class SomeCustomReactElement extends Component {
  doSomething() {
    console.log('do somthing');
  }
  render() {
    return <span>some custom react element</span>;
  }
}

export default class MyComponent extends Component {
  handleRef = (ref: SomeCustomReactElement) => {
    console.log('handle ref');
    ref.doSomething();
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <SomeCustomReactElement ref={this.handleRef} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

`index.test.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import MyComponent, { SomeCustomReactElement } from './';

describe('48349435', () => {
  it('should handle ref', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent />);
    const mRef = {
      doSomething: jest.fn(),
    };
    wrapper.find(SomeCustomReactElement).getElement()['ref'](mRef);
    expect(mRef.doSomething).toBeCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

unit test result:

```
 PASS  examples/48349435/index.test.tsx (7.984 s)
  48349435
    ✓ should handle ref (44 ms)

  console.log
    handle ref

      at Object.MyComponent.handleRef [as ref] (examples/48349435/index.tsx:14:13)

-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File       | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files  |   77.78 |      100 |      60 |   77.78 |                   
 index.tsx |   77.78 |      100 |      60 |   77.78 | 5-8               
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        10.273 s
```